# How do I get my Ubuntu install (in dual boot) to boot using UEFI?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi

I installed Xubuntu on my PC to set up a Windows VM with gpu pass-through for games. I checked to see if my PC is using uefi with `/sys/firmware/efi`.
The folder is missing so I tried to use

```
sudo apt install efibootmgr
```

but it says it's already on the latest version so I ran the command

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

and it says efi variables are not supported on this system.

I am running a ryzen 7 1700x, asus prime b350 plus 16 gb, gtx 1070, gtx 750ti. I have a Windows partition with Windows installed but I still don't get a menu on boot to select the OS and I have to change BIOS settings in order to switch between them.

Any recommendations? - Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily switch from BIOS to UEFI boot. First you need to enable UEFI in the VM before operating installation. The entire layout of the disk drive (boot loader, partition table, etc.) is different for UEFI compared to BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You have confirmed that Xubuntu is installed in legacy mode, and looks like Windows is in UEFI mode.

How the Xubuntu installation media is booted determines how it installs (legacy or UEFI), so check your BIOS/UEFI settings to make the install media boot in UEFI mode, and reinstall in UEFI mode.

Note that with Nvidia proprietary drivers, you probably want to turn Secure boot off, and edit the grub boot commands to add the word `nomodeset` along with the `quiet splash` words until the proprietaty Nvidia drivers have been installed.